# Javascript month calendar bug every end of the month

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Can someone explain to me the behavior of javascript why is it returning march right after january every end of the month?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setMonth(today.getMonth() + i); //0
  var month = today.toLocaleString('EN', {
    month: "long"
  });
  console.log(month);
}
```

> January, March, March, May, May, July, July, August, October, October, December, December

Comment: Are you expecting the date to be February 31st?

Comment: Because it's `01/31`. You add 1 to the month, so it's `02/31`...